# I am using soft assertion in my script but in case of failure, it is not continuing the rest if script and moving to next test case

Tags: testng, assertion

Here is my code:

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void verifyPageTitle () throws InterruptedException
{
String Actual_title=driver.getTitle();

String Expected_title = "Abc";

SoftAssert assertion = new SoftAssert(); //Soft Assertion
System.out.println("verifyPageTitle is started");

assertion.assertEquals(Actual_title, Expected_title, "URL doesn't n 
match");
assertion.assertAll();
System.out.println("verifyPageTitle is completed");
}
```

Here it is not printing "verifyPageTitle is completed"" however assertion fails.

Answer (score 1):

See [How To Use Soft Assert In TestNG | TestNG Tutorial](http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/soft-assert/).

> Soft Assert – Soft Assert collects errors during @Test. Soft Assert does not throw an exception when an assert fails and would continue with the next step after the assert statement.
>
> *If there is any exception and you want to throw it then you need to use `assertAll()` method as a **last statement** in the @Test and test suite again continue with next @Test as it is.*

And [from the TestNG API](http://javadox.com/org.testng/testng/6.8.7/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html)

> When an assertion fails, don't throw an exception but record the failure. *Calling `assertAll()` will cause an exception to be thrown if at least one [soft] assertion failed.*

That is, `SoftAssert#assertAll` will turn any "soft asserts" into "thrown exceptions" when called: if there are "failed soft asserts", calling `assertAll`, will terminate execution of the test immediately and thus skip any remaining code in the current test method.